# ¿Cómo sumar valores de un input y un select en tiempo real?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este `script`, que me permite sumar números en tiempo real:

```js
function operacion() {
  caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;
  var numero1 = Number(caja["cantidad"].value);
  var numero2 = Number(caja["costo"].value);
  var numero3 = Number(caja["monto_pagar"].value);
  var numero4 = Number(caja["descuento"].value);
  resultado = (numero1 * numero2);
  var desc = (numero1 * numero2) * numero4 / 100;
  caja["saldo_pagar"].value = (resultado - numero3) - desc;
  if (!isNaN(resultado)) {
    var descuento = (numero1 * numero2) * numero4 / 100;
    caja["total"].value = (numero1 * numero2) - descuento;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="sumar">
  <label>Cantidad</label>
  <input type="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad" onKeyUp="operacion()">
  <br>
  <label>Costo</label>
  <input type="text" name="costo" placeholder="Costo" onKeyUp="operacion()">
  <br>
  <label>Monto a pagar</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="monto_pagar" placeholder="Monto a pagar" onKeyUp="operacion()">
  <br>
  <label>Descuento</label>
  <input type="text" name="descuento" placeholder="Monto a pagar" onKeyUp="operacion()">
  <br>
  <label>SALDO</label>
  <input type="text" name="saldo_pagar">
  <br>
  <label>TOTAL</label>
  <input type="text" name="total">
</form>
```

Y funciona perfectamente.
Pero tengo ahora tengo el monto a pagar en un select, y tengo problemas al realizar esta operación.

```js
function operacion() {
  caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;
  var numero1 = Number(caja["cantidad"].value);
  var numero2 = Number(caja["costo"].value);
  var numero3 = Number(caja["monto_pagar"].value);
  var numero4 = Number(caja["descuento"].value);
  resultado = (numero1 * numero2);
  var desc = (numero1 * numero2) * numero4 / 100;
  caja["saldo_pagar"].value = (resultado - numero3) - desc;
  if (!isNaN(resultado)) {
    var descuento = (numero1 * numero2) * numero4 / 100;
    caja["total"].value = (numero1 * numero2) - descuento;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="sumar">
  <label>Cantidad</label>
  <input type="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad" onKeyUp="operacion()">
  <br>
  <label>Monto a pagar</label>
  <input type="text" name="monto_pagar" placeholder="Monto a pagar" onKeyUp="operacion()"> <br>
  <label>Costo</label>
  <select name="costo" onchange="operacion()">
<option value="200">200</option>
<option value="300">300</option>
<option value="400">400</option>
</select>
  <br> <label>Descuento</label>
  <input type="text" name="descuento" placeholder="Monto a pagar" onKeyUp="operacion()">
  <br>
  <label>SALDO</label>
  <input type="text" name="saldo_pagar">
  <br>
  <label>TOTAL</label>
  <input type="text" name="total">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por que no le pone un onchange al select.

Comment: Funcionó, gracias..

Answer (score 3):

El código que presento es una variación del código de la pregunta, tiene que tener todos los campos llenos y funcionaria en tiempo real, usando los eventos de `change` para el `select`, y `.on` para los campos.

```js
var numero3, numero1, numero2, numero4;
caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;
$(".monto_pagar").change(function() {
  numero3 = caja["monto_pagar"].value;
  mostrar();
});

$("#cantidad").on("input", function() {
  numero1 = Number(caja["cantidad"].value);
  mostrar();
});

$("#costo").on("input", function() {
  numero2 = Number(caja["costo"].value);
  mostrar();
});
$("#descuento").on("input", function() {
  numero4 = Number(caja["descuento"].value);
  mostrar();
});

function mostrar() {
  if (numero1 >= 0 && numero2 >= 0 && numero3 >= 0 && numero4 >= 0) {
    resultado = (numero1 * numero2);
    var desc = (numero1 * numero2) * numero4 / 100;
    caja["saldo_pagar"].value = (resultado - numero3) - desc;
    if (!isNaN(resultado)) {
      var descuento = (numero1 * numero2) * numero4 / 100;
      caja["total"].value = (numero1 * numero2) - descuento;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="sumar">
  <label>Cantidad</label>
  <input type="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad" id="cantidad">
  <br>
  <label>Costo</label>
  <input type="text" name="costo" placeholder="Costo" id="costo"> <br>
  <label>Monto a pagar</label>
  <select name="monto_pagar" class="monto_pagar">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">seleccione el monto</option>
<option value="200">200</option>
<option value="300">300</option>
<option value="400">400</option>
</select>
  <br> <label>Descuento</label>
  <input type="text" name="descuento" id="descuento" placeholder="Monto a pagar">
  <br>
  <label>SALDO</label>
  <input type="text" name="saldo_pagar">
  <br>
  <label>TOTAL</label>
  <input type="text" name="total">
</form>
```